# How can I detect whether the second gesture of sequensed was started or not at onEnded closure?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to handle two gestures: Simple short tap (via `DragGesture`) and long-tap with another DragGesture.

So, how can I detect what you have done: whether he/she has used short-tap or long-tap?

```
let sequencedDragGesture = DragGesture(
            minimumDistance: 0,
            coordinateSpace: .local
        ).onEnded { value in
            print("sequencedDragGesture \(self.touchState)")
        }
    let minimumLongPressDuration = 0.5
            let longPressDrag = LongPressGesture(
                minimumDuration: minimumLongPressDuration
            )
                .sequenced(before: sequencedDragGesture)
                .updating($dragState) { value, state, transaction in
                    print("before \(state)")
                    switch value {
                    case .first(true):
                        state = .pressing
    //                    self.isLongTapActivated = false
                    case .second(true, let drag):
    //                    self.isLongTapActivated = true
                        state = .dragging(translation: drag?.translation ?? .zero)
                    default:
                        state = .inactive
                    }
                    print("updating: \(state), \(self.dragState)")
                }
                .onChanged { _ in

                }
                .onEnded { value in
                    print("onEnded: \(self.touchState)")
                    guard case .second(true, let drag?) = value else {
                        return
                    }

                }


private enum DragState {
    case inactive
    case pressing
    case dragging(translation: CGSize)
}

@GestureState private var dragState = DragState.inactive
```

I can't use flags `isLongTapActivated`:

> Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined
>   behavior.

The problem is that at onEnded case I receive `.inactive`.
Is it possible in SwiftUI?

I read this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gestures/composing_swiftui_gestures

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using a class `Wrapper`:

```
final class Wrapper<T> {
    var state: T
    var isActivated: Bool = false
    init(_ state: T) {
        self.state = state
    }
}

extension Wrapper where T == DragState {
    func update(translation: CGSize) {
        operationQueue.addOperation {
            if self.isActivated {
                self.state = .dragging(translation: translation)
            } else {
                self.state = .pressing(translation: translation)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

updated `DragState`:

```
// MARK: - DragState

private enum DragState {
    case inactive
    case pressing(translation: CGSize)
    case dragging(translation: CGSize)

    var translation: CGSize {
        switch self {
        case .inactive, .pressing:
            return .zero
        case .dragging(let translation):
            return translation
        }
    }

    var isActive: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .inactive:
            return false
        case .pressing, .dragging:
            return true
        }
    }

    var isDragging: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .inactive, .pressing:
            return false
        case .dragging:
            return true
        }
    }
    var isPressing: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .pressing:
            return true
        case .inactive, .dragging:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

and mix with another 'Core' `DrawGesture`.

```
let sequencedDragGesture = DragGesture(
            minimumDistance: 0,
            coordinateSpace: .local
        )
        let minimumLongPressDuration = 0.5
        let longPressDrag = LongPressGesture(
            minimumDuration: minimumLongPressDuration
        )
            .sequenced(before: sequencedDragGesture)
            .updating($internalDragState) { value, state, transaction in
                switch value {
                case .first(true):
                    state = .pressing(translation: .zero)

                case .second(true, let drag):
                    if state.isPressing {
                        self.wrapper.isActivated = true
                        self.wrapper.update(translation: drag?.translation ?? .zero)
                    }


                    state = .dragging(translation: drag?.translation ?? .zero)
                default:
                    state = .inactive
                }
            }
        let dragGesture = DragGesture(
            minimumDistance: 0,
            coordinateSpace: .local
        )
        .onChanged { value in
            self.wrapper.update(translation: value.translation)
            print("changed: \(value), \(self.wrapper.state)")
        }
            .onEnded { value in
                print("onEnded Drag: \(self.wrapper.state)")
                self.wrapper.isActivated = false
                self.wrapper.state = .inactive
                print("\(self.internalDragState)")
        }

        let summGesture = longPressDrag
            .simultaneously(with: dragGesture)
```

where

```
@State private var wrapper = Wrapper<DragState>(.inactive)
```